# Wordpress - Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i'm creating a blog page in my custom theme wordpress, i would like use pagination in my list posts, my query with list of posts work well but the pagination doesn't work. i see always the same first 2 posts.

**page-blog.php**

```
/*
 * Template Name: Pagina Blog
 */

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php


$posts_per_page = 2;

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
  'offset'           => 0,
  'category'         => '',
  'category_name'    => '',
  'orderby'          => 'date',
  'order'            => 'DESC',
  'include'          => '',
  'exclude'          => '',
  'meta_key'         => '',
  'meta_value'       => '',
  'post_type'        => 'post',
  'post_mime_type'   => '',
  'post_parent'      => '',
  'author'     => '',
  'author_name'    => '',
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'suppress_filters' => true 
);
//$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
//query_posts( $args ); 

?>


  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <!-- Title -->

    <h1 class="my-4"><?php the_title() ?></h1>

    <h2 class="card-title">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>

  <!-- Content -->

    <?php the_content() ?>

  <!-- Pagination -->

    <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>

  <?php endwhile;

  // Reset Query
  wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I think there some issue with the loop, but i'm not sure, i can see "Newer" and "Older" links but when i go on older i see the same posts, so "www.mysite.com/blog" have the same post of "www.mysite.com/blog/2" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here lies your problem:

`'offset'           => 0,`

Replace that with:

`'offset' => $posts_per_page * ($paged - 1)`

Alternativley, if I'm reading the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) correctly, you can maybe just remove the offset value entirely.